# Use python def function to append for a list

Tags: python, function, append

There're a few categorical features in my dataset. I want to know how many unique numbers of each categorical feature coz I won't convert those with large unique numbers.

Instead of using `df['column name'].nunique()` to each feature one at a time, I want to get all numbers at once. Below, I'm trying to make a list of unique numbers per categorical column by defining a function but only get an empty list as result. I hope someone can figure out why my code doesn't work.

```
 #make a list of all categorical features
 
 cat_feats=['hotel','arrival_date_month','assigned_room_type','customer_type','deposit_type','distribution_channel','market_segment','meal','reserved_room_type',
 'country','reservation_status','reservation_status_date']
 

# define a function
 n_unique = [] 
def function(cat_feats):
    for x in cat_feats:
        n = hotel['x'].nunique()
        n_unique.append(n)
    return n_unique
```

Comment: use a code block

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your code completely, but `hotel['x'].nunique()` seems suspect when you just wrote a loop over a variable named `x`. Are you sure you want the quotation marks around the index?

Comment: So what is the problem here?...your function not working or what?

Comment: @AnuragDabas My code is not working. I'm expecting the function to return a list (n_unique) which consists of the number of distinct observations of each column in cat_feats. But there's no element in the list of n_unique.

Comment: @Blckknght I removed the quotation marks but get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating `list` of all categorical  and then using `for loop` and appending number of unique value to a new `list`

Just use this:-

```
n_unique=hotel.nunique().to_list()
```

Comment: It's beautifully simple!!